# Unable to use setOnClickListener on button in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have tried to add an `setOnClickListener` in my Fragment. But both methods i tried didnt work. There is no readction to my button press in the App.

```
class LoginFragment: Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    //AuthVariable for global use
    private lateinit var myAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_login, container, false)

        view?.login_button?.setOnClickListener(this)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        Log.i("BUTTON123","TEST")
        loginUser()

    }
}
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //AuthVariable for global use
    private lateinit var myAuth : FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        //Initializing FirebaseAuth Instance
        myAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        var user = myAuth.currentUser
        if(user != null){
            updateUI(user)
        }else{
            val test = supportFragmentManager
            val frag  = LoginFragment()
            test.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder,frag).addToBackStack(null).commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> return true
            else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_addShop -> {
                //Activity to Add your Shop
                val addshopIntent = Intent(this,AddShopActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(addshopIntent)

            }
            R.id.nav_searchShop -> {
                //SearchFragment
                val test = supportFragmentManager
                val frag  = test()
                test.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder,frag).addToBackStack(null).commit()

            }
            R.id.nav_shopMap -> {
                //MapActivity
                val mapintent = Intent(this, ShopMap::class.java)
                startActivity(mapintent)
            }
            R.id.nav_manage -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_share -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_logout -> {

                myAuth.signOut()
                updateUI(myAuth.currentUser)
            }
        }

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your activity code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget the `onClick()` method in `LoginFragment`?

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_login, container, false)

    view.login_button.setOnClickListener {
        Log.i("BUTTON123","TEST")
        loginUser()
    }

    return view
}
```

Comment: sry i somehow delted this part while coping the code

Comment: sadly not i looked on multiple pages, but still its not working

Comment: Did you put any code like a toast inside the onClick?

Comment: i put a Log.I in it which doesnt give any output. I added a toast. Stil no reaction

Comment: Is the id of the button login_button?

Comment: Remove all `?` from `view?.login_button?.setOnClickListener(this)` and see if you get error.

Comment: Remove then '?' Throws not Error at all, if i press the button. And still nothing happens

Comment: Move this line `view.login_button.setOnClickListener(this)` in `onViewCreated()`

Comment: Nothing changes when i move the line to 'onViewCreated()'

Comment: replace your onCreateView() with the one from my edited code

Comment: I'm glad_______